# adding multiple columns to pandas df (multi level columns)

Tags: python, pandas, multi-level

Hi I have a pandas df with multilevel columns:

```
sample = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.randn(10,2),columns=['a','b'])
df = pd.concat([samp], keys=['p4'],axis=1)
df
```

Output

```
    p4
    a           b
0   0.621016    0.920448
1   0.329792    -0.674688
```

I know I can add a column c like this:

```
df[('p4','c')] =df.p4.a - df.p4.b
df
```

Output:

```
    p4
    a            b           c
0   0.621016    0.920448    -0.299432
```

which adds the column 'c' with the right values to the level I want.

My question is how do I add a large number of these columns to a large dataframe without typing out the columns manually? For example I have columns (p5,['a','b']... (p6,['a','b']) I was thinking a for loop or a list comprehension but I'm strugling to figure out how to add the large number of calculated column 'c'

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, a loop is the most readable and maintainable way. For example:

```
for i in range(4, 11):
    df[('p'+str(i), 'c')] = df[('p'+str(i), 'a')] - df[('p'+str(i), 'b')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using MultiIndex for this

```
s=df.T.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x :  x.iloc[0]-x.iloc[1])

s.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([s.index,['c']])
pd.concat([df,s.T],1)
Out[956]: 
         p4                    
          a         b         c
0 -0.850052  0.960820 -1.810872
1 -0.217418  0.158515 -0.375933
2  0.873418 -0.111383  0.984802
3 -1.038039 -1.009480 -0.028559
4 -1.058257  0.656284 -1.714541
5 -0.062492 -1.738654  1.676163
6  0.103163 -0.621667  0.724830
7  0.275718 -1.090675  1.366393
8 -0.609985  0.306412 -0.916398
9  1.691826 -0.747954  2.439780
```